# Save bitmap when change layout

Tags: android, bitmap

I've a layout to portrait and a layout to landscape. In those layout, there is a ImageView with onClick listener. My ImageView has a default image (a camera icon)
When I push into ImageView, open a dialog and I can open camera and take a picture or open gallery and select a image.
Then, I save a bitmap and put it in the ImageView. This bitmap is a global variable in my class.

But when I turn my app, load my other layout (main_landscape) and if I took a pic, I lose my bitmap and charge default image.

This is my code:

```
public void takePicture(View view) {

    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take a pic", "Gallery","Cancel" };


    //Build an AlertDialog object
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
    builder.setTitle("Picture");

    //onClickListener method
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected) {
            if(options[selected].equals("Take a pic")){
                //open camera
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                //this is my global bitmap and I put it null when I push take a picture
                resized=null;
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else if(options[selected].equals("Gallery")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }
            else{
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            //if user doesn't select anything, show default icon
            //show picture is my layout ImageView and cameraicon is my default icon
            showPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.cameraicon);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

This is my onActivityResult code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    //if my resultCode is RESULT_OK
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode==1){
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for(File temp: f.listFiles()){
                if(temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")){
                    f=temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try{
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());

                newHeight=600;
                newWidth=900;
                //resized is my global bitmap
                resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

                //show my new bitmap in my ImageView
                showPicture.setImageBitmap(resized);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //I choose gallery option
        else if(requestCode==2){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath,null,null,null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            newHeight=600;
            newWidth=900;
            //my global bitmap
            resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, newHeight, newWidth, true);
            //show new bitmap in my ImageView
            showPicture.setImageBitmap(resized);
        }
    }
}
```

When I turn my phone, I loose my bitmap. What I can do, please?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You are not showing your `onCreate()` method which is kind of important here, as android by default destroys and recreates the top most activity on configuration changes (such as rotation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you save the value of your Bitmap by calling `onSaveInstaceState(Bundle bundle)` and then restore it when the activity is recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store the filename to your photo file inside the activity:

```
class MyActivity {
    File imageFile = null;
}
```

Since your activity will get destroyed on rotation, you need to save that image file name in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    if (imageFile != null) {          
          outState.putString("IMAGE_FILENAME", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Bitmaps in android are Parcelable, so instead of storing the filename of the image you could also save the `Bitmap` itself.

The saved state gets passed to `onCreate()` when your activity gets re-created:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    if (savedState != null) {
         String imagePath = saveState.getString("IMAGE_FILENAME");
         if (imagePath != null) {
             imageFile = new File(imagePath);
         }
    }
    updateImageView();
} 

public void updateImageView()
{
    // code from onActivityResult() to load the image
}
```

Side Notes:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
for (File temp: f.listFiles()) {
    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
        f = temp;
        break;
    }
}
```

You are writing to the global, external storage directory. Please don't do this, use your application's files' directory. Also, no need to search for a fixed filename in the path, simply check if the file exists.

```
File imageFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageFileName);
if (imageFile.exists()) {
   [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better way to do it is using fragment instead activity.
Use method fragment.setRetainInstance(true), and fragment will not be destroyed, when you turn your device.

Comment: The activity might get destroyed and re-created for other reasons, too.  So saving the instance state is more or less mandatory even though. 
`setRetainInstance(true)` lets your fragment live only across configuration changes, e.g. switching to another app might cause the image to disappear still.

Comment: Ok, it is an important amendment. Thanks